graph api get post title from facebook post
Hello i want get the title markert in following title:

my request was like below:
curl -i -X GET 
"https://graph.facebook.com/v19.0/8xxxxx_8xxxxx?fields=message%2Capplication%2Cstory%2Cstory_tags&since=2024-03-17T00%3A00%3A00&until=2024-04-19T00%3A00%3A00&access_token={{token}}"
it is impossible to get the title

I found by my selfe. Its an attachment attachments{url,media,description,title,type}
